# Bayesian classifier and discovery of new classifications

Tags: machine-learning, classification, k-means, naive-bayes

I've written Naive Bayesian classifiers before, they work wonderfully. But I'd like a classifier which will learn like a Bayesian classifier and identify new classifications when a new cluster emerges.

Lets presume I have sensor data for some sort of machinery. I have training data for different conditions - too hot, to cold, misfires, etc. Now lets assume some new condition occurs - say a misalignment, or say over revving.

What techniques would allow for that new cluster of data to build a new classification? Naive Bayes+K-Means?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more -- naive Bayes is a Bayesian classifier.

Comment: perhaps you want to check the likelihood of the data given the current model, and add a class to the model if the likelihood is low.

Comment: @suncoolsu I'm looking for a technique to extend Bayesian classification to be able to learn new classifications not present in initial training sets.

Comment: PLEASE register your account here and on Maths to reclaim your question and be able to edit and post comments. Just go to http://math.stackexchange.com/login and then to http://stats.stackexchange.com/login .

Comment: @Milton and that's exact what a naive Bayes will do. Basically, you ant to predict (or learn) a new classification based on your previous naive Bayes fit, and choosing to use a Bayesian models takes care of that. (using penalized estimators will give similar answers).